# Inline javascript with thymeleaf escaping character

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, html-escape-characters

I use thymeleaf and spring.
I try to do inline javascript.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

    $("#genericTable").bootstrapTable({
        url: /*[[${url}]]*/ 'generic',
        ...
     });
```

On the server side I do

```
 model.addAttribute("url", "/rest/vehicles");
```

I get

> url: "\/rest\/vehicles",

Why some caracters are added to the string?

Edit

with

```
url: /*[[@{${url}}]]*/ 'generic',
```

first / is like removed, so it's invalid to call...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it : which extra characters do you get?

Comment: i updated, \ character is added

Comment: J think that's because it makes a kind of escaping of the /. That's why for URLs there's a special syntax. See here, there's a section about URL rewriting. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

Comment: Have you tried to generate it outside the Javascript comment? For example, as a text directly in HTML (using the @, of course). In case what do you get?

Comment: if i use only:  @{${url}}   nothing is generated

Comment: Sorry, I mean outside the whole javascript block. Check what's generated when you just write it as a URL in HTML code. All the examples are always with something like "/path/to/@{value}". Maybe it ignores the first /.

Comment: I know it looks ugly, but does escaping the forward slash cause any problems? That is, even though `url: "\/rest\/vehicles"` appears in the JavaScript _code_, isn't the resulting string still `"/rest/vehicles"`? If you do a `console.log(…)` of the value, won't it log `"/rest/vehicles"`? What is the actual problem here other than aesthetics of the JavaScript source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
    $("#genericTable").bootstrapTable({
        url: /*[[${url}]]*/ 'generic',
        ...
    });  
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Please note that this answer is from September 2017, things may have changed in these years...

Answer (score 8):

`[(...)]` should help

Example with problem I am facing:

```
$.getJSON('[[@{/management/users/search/unit/}]]' + value, function(data) {
```

Is transformed to:

```
$.getJSON('"\/management\/users\/search\/unit\/"' + value, function(data) {
```

Using `[(...)]`:

```
$.getJSON('[(@{/management/users/search/unit/})]' + value, function(data) {
```

Is transformed to:

```
$.getJSON('/management/users/search/unit/' + value, function(data) {
```

From [Thymeleaf 3.0 docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining)

> Note that, while [[...]] corresponds to th:text (i.e. result will be HTML-escaped), [(...)] corresponds to th:utext and will not perform any HTML-escaping.

Comment: Assume that there is code like: $.getJSON("[(@{/some/url(param=${someUserInput})})]") , there is a risk of javascript code injection vulnerability here... For this specific scene, while s is generated string, s.replace("\/", "/") might be a better choice, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a little old but the answer don't correct the problem, or the same I faced. To remove escaping I suggest to write code like this (double quotes are here only for javascript purpose)  :

```js
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
    $("#genericTable").bootstrapTable({
        url: "[(@{ ${url} })]",
        ...
    });  
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```